# Redirect to index.php in root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've written the following code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [END]
```

It works perfect for every path, except for directories that exist. For example, if I enter `http://localhost/profilepic` and such directory actually exists, it **redirects** to `http://localhost/profilepic/?route=profilepic`, but I want it to be *implicitly* converted to `http://localhost/index.php?route=profilepic`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of [mod_dir and the `DirectorySlash` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). Essentially, if it sees a URI without a trailing slash, and it maps to an existing directory, then it'll redirect the request so that it has the trailing slash. Since mod_dir and mod_rewrite are both in different places in URL-file processing pipeline, both mod_dir and mod_rewrite get applied to the same URL. That's why you end up with a redirect and a weird URL with the query string.

If you absolutely must have directories without trailing slashes, then you need to turn of `DirectorySlash`. The problem with turning it off is that there is an information disclosure security concern that will make it so people can look at the contents of a directory *even if you have an index file*. That means you have to make up for mod_dir using mod_rewrite.

So get rid of the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
```

and replace it with these rules:

```
DirectorySlash Off

# redirect direct requests that end with a slash to remove the slash.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+[^\?\ ]+/($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]

# internally add the trailing slash for directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you can have your rules without turning off `DirectorySlash` (considered a security hole):

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash for non-directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# routing for directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /index.php?route=$1 [L]

# routing for non directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Comment: +1 for this nice solution. Tnx.
BTW, What does L mean?

Comment: L is to mark a rule as `Last` which re-injects the rewritten URL to mod_rewrite engine.